# Uncaught Range Error in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I am getting an Uncaught Range Error in Chrome, but chrome does not show me which line or file the recursion (looks like a mutual recursion here)is happening. 
Is there any easy way to locate the place where this recursion is happening, or a way to break when the stack size is about to exceed?
Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Do you have your Dev Tools open while running this (not just after)? It should show you the line number if you do.

Comment: There might be better ways, but there are always good, old `console.log`s :)

Comment: @PaulDraper I do have my dev tools open all the time, it still does not show me the line or file

Comment: @ExpertSystem I am not even sure where to start adding the debug statements! I am not even sure which file is causing the problem

Comment: Ok I just tried it out in latest version of Chrome Canary(Version 32.0.1683.2 canary) and it works, It did not show me the line numbers in Version 30.0.1599.101. Anyway I can debug in Canary for a while I guess.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [known bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=272742) which was fixed some time ago. The [Canary](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/canary.html) builds already contain the fix and should solve the problem.